# Authorization has been denied for this request while hitting api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, auth0

Was following one example in one tutorial related to Auth0. I am able to get token but when i used postman to hit my api and passed below parameter to my header then i get "Authorization has been denied for this request" error.

```
GET /api/shipments HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:36740
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhl GciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL215Zmlyc3RhdXRoLmV1LmF1dGgwLmNvbS8iLCJzdWIiOiJhdXRoMHw1OGI5ZTAwZjEyYzk4ZTQzODEzNTlhNDQiLCJhdWQiOiJONlNzR0dxNTJmd2NmTnRUUmRoR2Zab2VHcFBpS05aTCIsImV4cCI6MTQ4ODYxNjg5MSwiaWF0IjoxNDg4NTgwODkxfQ.16-GRBQiwEbqXLH76plOHtLGuGvoaDYKCawoRT7goyg
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: d3622cb1-0ed8-e290-cc85-c5b10161d0c1
```

Here is code in my startup.cs

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace MyProj.WebAPI
{
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth0(app);
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}
```

}

And here is code from AuthZeroConfig class

```
public partial class Startup
{
    private void ConfigureAuth0(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var issuer = "https://" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["auth0:Domain"];
        var audience = "https://" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["auth0:ClientId"];
        var secret = TextEncodings.Base64.Encode(
            TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["auth0:ClientSecret"]));

        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
            AllowedAudiences = new[] {audience},
            IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new[]
            {
                new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, secret)
            }

        });
    }
}
```

What i do to solve this?

Comment: can you offer your Tenant name? I will then give you a working CURL request - that way you will have all the information you need to get this working with code. Should be easy enough from that point.

Comment: @arcseldon what is tenant name? where do i find it?

Comment: @Happy - followed the same tutorial and met with the same issue (in fact that's where I found your link). I'm still trying to figure out what's wrong with it, but it looks like just very poor job by provider updating it to newer libraries. In the meantime I can recommend this tutorial (free!) that worked great for me: http://www.developerhandbook.com/c-sharp/create-restful-api-authentication-using-web-api-jwt/